# Flask - Logging in Blueprint doesn't show Module Name

Tags: python, flask, logging

I have created a blueprint for logging with before_app_request and after_app_request.
I am using a custom Logger which is used throughout my whole application.

The problem is, that every log entry made by before_app_request or after_app_request only shows the module name "flask_api_blueprint".

flask_api_blueprint.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from myLogger import myLoggerFile


api_blueprint = Blueprint('api_blueprint', __name__)


@api_blueprint.before_app_request
def log_incoming_request():
    myLoggerFile.getLogger().info("INCOMING REQUEST")
```

flask_api_example.py:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_api_blueprint import api_blueprint
from myLogger import myLoggerFile


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)

logger = myLoggerFile.getLogger()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    logger.info("Index called!")
    file_A.do_something()  # also uses myLoggerFile.getLogger() 
    return "Hello World"
```

The log entry looks like this:

```
[2020-04-09 13:29:56,011] 127.0.0.1 requested http://127.0.0.1:5000/ - INFO in flask_api_blueprint: INCOMING REQUEST
```

I want this entry to say "flask_api_example" instead of "flask_api_blueprint".
How can I change this to use my own logger while logging the correct module name, which uses the blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

So, the only solution I found is, to reassign the module name by defining my Logger's formatter the following way:

```
from flask import current_app

class RequestFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        if flask.has_request_context():
            record.module = current_app.name
        return super().format(record)
```